# Django channels - how to send messages to groups from an external script?

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I have a very simple Django channels consumer that subscribes clients to a group:

```
class TestConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

    async def websocket_connect(self, event):

        await self.accept()
        await self.send_json('Connected')
        
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            'GROUP1',
            self.channel_name
        )

    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        pass

    async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            'GROUP1',
            self.channel_name
        )
```

And then, in the same server but outside of the Django application, i have a script that receives data from a websocket server:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello():
    uri = "ws://SOME-URL"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        data = await websocket.recv()
        print(json.loads(data))
```

Is there any way i can send the data received in the second script to users subscribed to `GROUP1` in the Django Channels app? So basically every time the second script receives a new message, that message must be sent from the Django Channels app to its clients. For various reasons i can't run the second script in a Django management command, is there another way to do this?

Comment: What's the reason(s) for not being able to run it in a management command/channels worker?

Comment: It's basically that i'm planning the second script to do a lot of operations, so it will have more files with variables and everything, and putting all of that inside of the django app would make everything a bit messy

Comment: So long as you name and organise your directories and files appropriately there's no reason you can't have the second script in the Django app but in it's own directory. The benefit of being able to just use the Django channels code directly surely outweighs any desire to have things separated

Comment: Yes maybe i should do that, it's just that i was thinking that using a management command would not be as versatile as it being a completely separated script

Comment: You can always refactor. Get it working first in the simplest form and after developing and monitoring it you should have more insight into how it should finally be architected

Comment: This answer and many others in stackoverflow show how to interact with Django Channels from outside the consumer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58941923/3442256