# Web-sockets & Django

Tags: javascript, django, web, websocket

This is a table of posts, I want to update the status(red highlighted) whenever a user comments on a post. I used WebSockets to show real-time comments on the page(if the tab is open comments will show without page refresh). But if a user posts a comment I want to update this status in real-time.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had you look this post?

[Django-channels sending message when model changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58914833/django-channels-sending-message-when-model-changes)

You can use something like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver

...

@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=Comment)
def send_comment(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)("chat_name", {"type": "send_comment"})
```

You can find more signals options at [Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/) and more about channel layers outside of consumers at [here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#using-outside-of-consumers)